# A non ssl request to ssl server?

Tags: ssl, https, server

As the internet of things is becoming more and more mainstream , there is a growing need of sending `http` requests from  hardware .

One main problem is that hardware micro controllers are not capable of sending `ssl` requests , but most server/websites/services are using `ssl` .

So, question is , is there any bridge( a service) that you can send to it a `http` request, he will wrap it with `ssl`, send it to the endpoint, then get the respond from the endpoint, unwrap back the `ssl` , and send it back to the sender ?

For example, using `parse.com` requires ssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to do this - you could, for example, run `stunnel` in client mode on a machine you trust. It's a lightweight proxy that does what you describe: turn non-SSL connections into SSL connections and vice versa.

You could also use `nginx` as a proxy, which will also take care of doing some HTTP-specific rewriting:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://wandernauta.nl:443/;
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases, *everything between your proxy and the 'internet thing' will be unencrypted*, which means it can be intercepted, modified, and tampered with.

For more, see the [stunnel website](https://www.stunnel.org) and the
[nginx website](https://www.nginx.org).

Comment: thanks, but this should serve lots of users, so can it be on some remote server ? another thing that bother me, is that you need to somehow provide it with the endpoint data expect from your original request, so your request cant be as it used to be ..

Comment: wow it seems not a really straight forward approach that requires much more experience that i have..

Comment: I've added a minimal example config for nginx that you could use as a starting point.

Comment: when you say that unencrypted data can be modified, is it not true also for ssl data? you cant read it, but if you can modified any other request you can also modify an ssl one ? ( btw, so you say that any device without ssl is just wide open? what if i encrypt the data field itself with AES ? )

Comment: Yes, TLS/SSL-encrypted data can technically be modified, but if you try to do anything funny, it will immediately be rejected by the client.  Browsers will maybe show a big scary red error message, or just drop the connection altogether.

Comment: AES is one of the encryption standards that SSL can use (my browser is using it right now in talking to StackOverflow!), so if your hardware controller is capable of, and powerful enough for, AES encryption you can probably just use SSL. Don't [roll your own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/71654) if you can avoid it.

Comment: So a regular http is not encrypted. Does the ssl encrypt the whole message or just the body of the post/get request? What if i will encrypt only the body using aes? (The wifi module cant do ssl or aes he just mirror requests)